# python3.7.9 forget Frame

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I Want to collapse the Frames in the main window:

```
import tkinter as tk

def main():
    main=tk.Tk()
        
    main.window = ClassOfFrameT(main).grid(row=0,column=0)
    #I Want to grid_forget() the ClassOfFrame Frame
    
    main.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tryed something like `main.windodw.grid_forget()` but `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'RadiosVehicle'` was the error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter: AttributeError: NoneType object has no attribute <attribute name>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101750/tkinter-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-attribute-name)

Comment: `ClassOfFrameT(main)` whats this? Shouldnt it be `tk.Frame(..)` and then `grid()` it in the next line and then change your `def main()` to something else, so python isnt confused between function and window variable. Also try giving a proper variable name